# How to show cookie content after page reload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

My default.aspx form tag content is

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Height="47px" Width="176px" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCookie" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

What I want to accomplish is that the Textbox is filled with the string I wrote into the textbox and saved via the bottom after closing the page and reopen it.
My text behind is

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    TextBoxCookie.Text = Request.Cookies("TextCookie").Value
End Sub

Protected Sub ButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click
    Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("TextCookie")
    aCookie.Value = TextBoxCookie.Text.ToString
    aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
End Sub
```

But after closing the page the textbox is empty. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with the code because I am not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You only want to set the value of `TextBoxCookie` if the page *isn't* a post back. Otherwise, your page flow is for you to type in a value, click the button, then on post back you are overwriting the value that you typed with the value of the cookie (which is probably empty). Then, `ButtonSave_Click` executes and sets the cookie to the value of the textbox (which is now empty and *not* what you typed).
2. Be aware that `ButtonSave_Click` occurs *after* `Page_Load`. Please review the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.140).aspx).

So, only set the value the Textbox when it isn't a post back... something like

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        TextBoxCookie.Text = Request.Cookies("TextCookie").Value
    End If
End Sub
```